# Redirect certain page to new page with same id

Tags: php, redirect

I need to redirect certain pages to specific page with same ID :

Example:

```
http://mydomain/?en/273/gallery/711-19-24
http://mydomain/?en/273/gallery/711-19-25
http://mydomain/?en/273/gallery/711-19-32
http://mydomain/?en/273/gallery/others-9000-ID
```

to:

```
http://mydomain/newfolder/pics/711-19-24
http://mydomain/newfolder/pics/711-19-25
http://mydomain/newfolder/pics/711-19-32
http://mydomain/newfolder/pics/others-9000-ID
```

Is it possible to do that using 301 Moved Permanently with php? Or are there others solutions?

EDIT:

i have something like 9000 different dinamic ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a php page which routes these in the first place, and assuming your examples are accurate:

```
$queryStringKeys=array_keys($_GET);
if(count($queryStringKeys)==1)
{
    $queryStringParts=explode('/',$queryStringKeys[0]); // gets array of url separated by /

    // check it's the 273/gallery format
    if(strpos($queryStringKeys[0],'273/gallery')>0)
    {
        $lastPart=$queryStringParts[count($queryStringParts)-1];
        Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        Header('Location: /newfolder/pics/'.$lastPart);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you got an ID variable somewhere. You could put a header to each of these pages with the ID?

```
header("location:http://page.com/newfolder/pics/'$id'");
```

Or simply change the links instead with the same idea.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand... in this way i continue to see page.com? I try to explain: i need to redirect only requests for incoming page that have this directory: page.com/?en/273/gallery/ maintaining the ID. While page.com/aboutus or page.com/contact are right.

Answer (score 0):

You could explode the url by `\` and redirect by that:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if( strpos( $url, 'mydomain/' ) !== false ) {
        $exploded_url = explode('/',$url);
        $last = end($exploded_url);
}

Header('Location: /newfolder/pics/'.$last);
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work. Any way, thank you.